# why does scanf not store ascii value of character in an integer variable properly?

Tags: c

```
  int ch;
  scanf("%c", &ch); //Read a character (%c)
  printf("You entered char %c %d\n", ch, ch);
  return 0;
```

expected output:  You entered char A 65 **Actual output: You entered char A 32577**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have to store it in a `char` and not an `int`.

When you compile your code you should have this warning:

```
warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%c", &ch); //Read a character (%c)
          ~^   ~~~
          %lc
```

If you don't want to use a `char` type you can also change format to `%lc`.

This happens because scanf will convert the value into the desired type. In your example it will store 1 byte in a 4 bytes type. Since your `int ch` is uninitialized you'll have the 3 remaining bytes of memory uninitialized, hence the wrong value.

Try initializing it `int ch = 0;` and you'll have the correct value.

Comment: why does it matter ? ASCII that conatins upto 128 values can easily be stored in int varaible.

Comment: I've edited my answer, in short set `ch = 0` before scanf and you'll fix your problem.

Comment: "in short set ch = 0 before scanf and you'll fix your problem" --> relies on an assumed endian - not a good approach.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica What should be done in the other case ?

Answer (score 2):

1. `ch` is of type int and `scanf("%c", &ch)` copies a `byte` in to address location pointed by `&ch`.
2. Machine [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) decides where the `char` value from iostream stored. if `ch` on stack garbage values present in remaining bytes of `ch`